# AngularJS Directive $location.path() returns empty string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hoping someone can shed some light on this:

I have a simple directive in which `$location.host()` & `$location.protocol()` always returns an empty string.

MyDirective.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('KeirSimpleApp')
.directive('ims', ['$rootScope', '$window', '$log', '$location', function($rootScope, $window, $log, $location) {
    var url = '';
    if($location.path().indexOf('qe') > -1) {
        //do something
        url = $location.host();
    }



    return {
        template: '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://' + $location.host() + '"></script>',

        restrict: 'E',

        link: function() {
            $rootScope.userState = {
                isUserSignedIn: false
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

App.js:

```
'use strict';
angular
  .module('ersUiApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/index.html', {
                templateUrl: 'components/main/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .when('/preview', {
                templateUrl: 'components/preview/preview.html',
                controller: 'PreviewCtrl'
            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true
        }).hashPrefix();
    })  
    .constant('_', window._)
    .run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
     $rootScope._ = window._;
  });
```

Please let me know if I need to be more verbose. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the controller actually invoked? What url are you visiting? `example.com/#/index.html` looks like a weird naming convention for routes - what is the .html in the route for?

Comment: Thanks for the comment... Unsure what I was doing wrong but I've got things working now!